Bought a Minolta Minolta AF 70-210mm f/ 4 lens can it fit on my Canon Rebel T7 body?
Bought a Minolta AF 70-210mm f/ 4 and I use a rebel T7 is there a adapter available to use for them?

Life tip - check before buying
